# Authenticating request manually producing error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am authenticating request with custom auth token filter

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public AuthTokenFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager= authenticationManager;
}


 @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("Adsmsditdssfd@Gmail.com","ABC@!@#");
    SecurityContext sc= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    sc.setAuthentication(authentication);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", sc);
}

}
```

but i am getting exception while request is processed in doFilterInternal of above filter  at this below line

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
```

exception is

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isEqualsMethod(AopUtils.java:151) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:175) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: I assume it is going through another filter, inside that it is throwing null pointer. 
Can you update the complete error log.?